# How to know if material-ui TextField was truncated

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield

I have given a custom styling to my **TextField** mui component like below:

```
'& > * .MuiFilledInput-input': {
  overflow: 'hidden',
  textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
},
```

This is to show the ellipsis when the text is truncated inside TextField. This works fine but now I need to show a tooltip only when the text is truncated. So somehow I need to find out if the **TextField** used above styling or if the text was truncated. I do not want to use hard-coded length/width approach but instead find it out dynamically. Any ideas how to do it?